# Call function in html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm fairly new to the whole ASP.NET and I'm struggling to get the html to load my functions.

So I have this basic ASP.NET Web Form that I used, when I click on "Click this" it should show the connection string but I have no idea as to what I'm doing wrong.

I currently have this in the Default.aspx:

```
        <a ID="MyAnchor"
           OnServerClick="Page_Load"
           runat="server">
           Click This
        </a>
```

And this in the Default.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

I'm guessing I'm not really updating the text in the html since I'm not doing anything with my connectionString, am I right?

How can I let it update the text then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'it should show the connection string'? Where your connecting string should be shown? Which function do you want to do it?

Comment: @Dnyanesh In my html I have the "Click this" hyperlink, if I click it the "Click this" should change to the connectionstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing I'm not really updating the text in the html since I'm not doing anything with my connectionString, am I right?

That's right. It would be pretty bad if every local variable were implicitly placed in the generated HTML.

> How can I let it update the text then?

You named your element `MyAnchor`, which should let you access that element by name in your C# code. You can set its [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

If you want to display the text somewhere else, place another control somewhere else, and set the text of that instead.

Note: you may want to use the `asp:*` controls (such as `asp:HyperLink`), which are typically a bit easier to manipulate code-wise.